# Different Java developer and program versions?

Tags: eclipse, java

I've installed JDK7 java version and selected version 7 as the JVM in Eclipse. The version of compiler remains being 1.6 and it doesn't shows a greater version.
Is it correct?
Thanks

Comment: Did you select the JVM Eclipse is running in or the JDK version used for your project? - Please also note that Java 7 is quite new and Eclipse might not yet fully support it.

Comment: Careful with Java 7 just now, there are some nasty bugs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894104/how-serious-is-the-java7-solr-lucene-bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Current version of Eclipse (3.7) does not support compiling Java 7 sources yet. The support is coming in 3.7.1 update soon. You can **run** your application with Java 7 JRE, but there is no support for compilation at the moment.