# Is Java 7 at least as stable as Java 6?

Tags: java, java-7, jvm-hotspot

I remember when Java 7 was initially released, there were many suggestions [not to use it for anything](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/07/28/dont-use-java-7-for-anything/) as there were some bugs in compiler optimizations.  This was apparently [not merely hypothetical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6894104/387852).  I haven't followed the situation closely since then; have these issues been worked out and it is generally considered safe to use at this point?

[This page](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java7.xml) from java.com makes me think perhaps it's not quite ready yet, but I don't want to read too much into it.  If it is not yet safe, is it sufficient to use `-XX:-UseLoopPredicate` as a VM argument?

Note that I am not only referring to the specific Lucene issue but the general stability of Java 7.  Is Java 7 at least as stable as Java 6?

Comment: The bug reported, which made Lucene (and Eclipse) crash, has been fixed.

Comment: [`This means you cannot use Apache Lucene/Solr with Java 7 releases before Update 2!`](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/07/28/dont-use-java-7-for-anything/). [Java Platform (JDK) 7u2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

Comment: How should anyone know about the "general stability" of Java 7 in a way that's suitable for SO? (I.e. what answers do you expect besides what's basically a gut feeling?)

Comment: @Inerdial I don't know if there are any standards, but there could be.  For instance, there could be an independent test suite by a 3rd party or something.  Nobody can know if something is bug-free, but it's conceivably possible to answer this question with something besides gut feeling.

Comment: @Inerdial Also the existence or non-existence of any sort of consensus among developers would seem appropriate for an answer.

Comment: A "consensus among developers" is more or less an aggregated gut feeling, as well as probably bad-subjective-question territory. As far as the hypothethical test suite goes, that would be better suited to a separate question.

Comment: @Inerdial: *"How should anyone know about the general stability of Java 7 in a way that's suitable for SO?"*  Simply make it like this: *"Is it as stable as the latest Java 6 is?"*.  Sounds quite simple to me : )

Comment: It worth remembering that JVM version 6 and 7 is much the same except there are different options on/off by default.

Comment: For those that think this is too localized, note that I am **not** just asking about the specific Lucene issue.

Comment: Have you stopped beating your wife yet?

Comment: @CodyGray I see what you did there.  Is there a different reason you or others think it's too localized?

Comment: For reference, here is what the CEO of Stack Overflow [thinks about "too localized"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87415/158779).

Comment: I didn't vote to close this as "too localized". It doesn't seem like a particularly bad question. I just intended my comment as a subtle prod to consider modifying the title slightly. (I secretly suspect that's what is prompting some of the close votes. They just couldn't find the "inflammatory" reason.)

Comment: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120081/158779) is a discussion on Meta.SO about whether this is too localized.

Answer (score 14):

From the [very article you linked to](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/07/28/dont-use-java-7-for-anything/):

> **UPDATE OCTOBER 28, 2011:** As noted on Uwe’s blog, [Java 7u1 is documented to include the patches to address these issues](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2011/10/java-7-update-1-released-does-it-fix.html).

The article *that* links to says:

> Last night, **Oracle updated the release notes of Java 7u1 and Java 6u29**, stating that they fixed the three Lucene-relevant bugs (plus another one related to that). *Based on this confirmation, it's now safe to use Java 7 Update 1 (and later) with Apache Lucene and Apache Solr.*

This answer paid for by The Committee For Clicking On Links For You.

Comment: A subsidiary of Read Your Own Links productions

Comment: I wasn't referring exclusively to the Lucene issue; it is just the noteworthy example.

Answer (score 1):

The [major bug](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/07/28/dont-use-java-7-for-anything/) that Uwe Schindler from Lucene and Solr annouced was fixed in Java7u1 (read more from him [here](http://blog.thetaphi.de/2011/10/java-7-update-1-released-does-it-fix.html). I believe it's safe to use Java7 now, especially given that there has also been a [second update](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u2-relnotes-1394228.html) released for it that "improves reliability and performance".

Comment: a second update that *"improves reliability"* is **really** not something I like to read.  It reads like *"first update wasn't reliable, this second update is bit more reliable"*.  :(

Comment: @user988052 "improves reliability and performance" is the standard corporate boilerplate for "we fixed some stuff we can't be bothered to enumerate". Cf. every Apple release notes ever.

Comment: @user988052: Back in 2002, I co-authored a [paper that looked at how often security patches had to be re-released because the first patch was incorrect](http://citeseer.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.129.6492) -- out of 136 vulnerabilities, 92 had good "first patches", 20 patches had subsequent patches, and 4 of _those_ were faulty. Perhaps the world has improved in ten years, but I'd be surprised. :)